# Term for "county and municipality", administrative units dividing a country

Tags: word-request, terminology

Instead of *brother or sister*, we can say *sibling*. Instead of *password and username*, we can say *credentials*.

A compressed form with a stricter style provides a formal sensation. I'd like to achieve that for the governmental units of division for my country. Our kingdom is divided into 30 counties and each of those is divided in a total of 300 municipalities.

How can I say *county and/or municipality* using a single word (or at least a collective term not mentioning those explicitly)? Is there a formal term for *govermentally statued administrative units of geographical division* but a bit shorter?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is essentially an "antonym" of ***nationwide***. For which ***local*** or ***regional*** might suit certain contexts, but for other contexts you might consider things like ***federal, state-level, county-level, provincial,...*** Or even ***parochial*** (in the geographical sense "of the parish", not "small-minded, sectarian").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a uncommon enough topic that there is little consensus on which phrase to use.

For instance, one relatively common term would be **administrative division**. This phrase seems sufficient, yet it's often used inconsistently:

[*Encyclopædia Britanica*](https://www.britannica.com/topic/county) describes a county as an "internal territorial and **administrative division** in the United Kingdom, United States, and other English-speaking countries." But on that same page, we see: "County:
**division of government**"

China's Minsitry of Foreign Affairs (maybe not the best source of good English usage) describes its ["Administrative Division System"](https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/ljzg_665465/zgjk_665467/3572_665469/t1140993.shtml) thus:

> **Administrative Division System**
>
> China's **administrative *units*** are currently based on a three-level system...A special administrative region is a local **administrative *area*** directly under the Central Government.

Other reasonable options include *administrative unit/entity/region*, *subnational unit*, or *country subdivision*.

This Wikipedia article lists all of these and more: ["Administrative division"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division).

Another term, as suggested by @JeffZeitlin, would be *jurisdiction*. NB that *jurisdiction* has a much less general meaning than administrative division, as explained above.

Comment: ...and if you're talking about law, you might see the word ***jurisdictions*** come into play.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin So, in my case, *jurisdictional units*? Or is is *jurisdictious units*?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - actually, it would probably be just ***jurisdictions*** in your case; it really depends on context.For example, a New York City police officer does not have arrest powers in Newark, New Jersey; he is "out of his jurisdiction" - New York, Newark, Yonkers, Mount Vernon, and so on are separate jurisdictions.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Brilliant! I was so expecting at least two-word compound that I missed the actually intended point in your suggestion. So dumb... You might want to post it as an answer or perhaps edit the existing answer amending your contribution.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, note that *jurisdiction* has a much less general meaning than *administrative division* (or the other alternatives I've listed). There are cases where you could refer to a county, for instance, as a jurisdiction, but that would be somewhat rare.  If you edit your original question to include the specific context you'd like to use this phrase in, we can provide better answers. My answer is for the general question: what do we call the category of things that includes states, counties, municipalities, etc.

Comment: Agreed. Although, in my particular case, *jurisdiction* is perfect due to brevity (still covering the original intent, of course - brevity's merely a cherry on top). Is it OK if I edit your answer to add that as well, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about US usage but in the UK county councils, city councils, town councils, district councils, borough councils, metropolitan boroughs, parish councils and unitary authorities are all "local authorities" of various types. Some have more responsibilities than others and some are subordinate to others in some ways but they are all local authorities.

This is somewhat parallel to the way in which "siblings" is a word meaning "brothers and sisters" but is actually more similar to "family members" which includes parents, grandparents, children, grandchildren, cousins, nieces, nephews and so on.

If there are no more divisions of responsibility in your country than counties and municipalities then "local authorities" would be a good fit: if, however, there are other layers of administration such as village councils below the municipalities which you wish to exclude from your group term I think you might struggle to find one.

Comment: Good point. As a matter of fact, my intention is to keep it a bit vague, although hierarchical, to be able to incorporate future administrative weirdifications.   :)